# Cypress- Wait till element changes status

Tags: user-interface, dom, cypress

I have some UI tests using Cypress, where there is an span element (#done-status) which initially has value '', followed by 'In Progress' and then 'Complete'. After it changes to 'Complete', I want to assert the value of another element (#failures) to be 0. The state change from empty string to In Progress and to Complete takes some time depending on some execution. How can I wait till it changes it's status. I tried random waits but since the element is already on the DOM, it doesn't wait for the timeout and it fails. Something like this :

```
it('should verify if the tests passed', () => {

        cy.get('#done-status')
            .should('have.value', '');

        cy.get('#done-status', { timeout: 10000 })
            .should('have.value', 'In Progress')

        cy.get('#done-status', { timeout: 300000 })
            .should('have.value', 'Complete');

        cy.get('.failures')
            .should('have.value', 0);
 });
```

Is there a way so that it can wait till the state changes and at the end verify the number of failures.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try to wait()? . But it may make the test flaky

Comment: I think you may have more luck with `.should('have.text', ...)`. You have a good sequence of commands, so no  need for additional libraries.

Comment: What you have should work, assuming of course you're truly looking for `value=blahblah` instead of the text. If you're looking for the text, use `have.text` like Steve suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until) plugin for this.

1.For installation:

```
npm i -D cypress-wait-until
```

2.Once installed, go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write:

```
import 'cypress-wait-until';
```

3.In your tests write:

```
cy.waitUntil(() =>
  cy.get('#done-status').then($ele =>
    $ele[0].value == 'Complete',

    //timeouts
    {
      timeout: 20000, // waits up to 2000 ms
      interval: 500 // performs the check every 500 ms
    }
  )
)
cy.get('.failures').should('have.value', 0);
```